# Как перехватить событие появления/скрытия виртуальной клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, monotouch, ios

Собственно вопрос.

Пойдет ссылка и на Objective-C.

Приложение не фоновое.

Просто надо менять лайаут под размер клавы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При появлении и скрытии клавиатуры iOS рассылает сообщение, которое может перехватить любой объект текущего приложения. Сообщения отправляются через центр уведомлений, который называется `NSNotificationCenter`.

Чтобы перехватить определенное сообщение, объект должен подписаться на него. Для этого он должен знать имя уведомления. Например, вот список уведомлений для отлавливания появления/скрытия клавиатуры:

```
// Each notification includes a nil object and a userInfo dictionary containing the
// begining and ending keyboard frame in screen coordinates. Use the various UIView and
// UIWindow convertRect facilities to get the frame in the desired coordinate system.
// Animation key/value pairs are only available for the "will" family of notification.
NSString *const UIKeyboardWillShowNotification;
NSString *const UIKeyboardDidShowNotification; 
NSString *const UIKeyboardWillHideNotification; 
NSString *const UIKeyboardDidHideNotification;
```

Для того, чтобы получить эти уведомления, надо на них подписаться. Например так:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeShown:)
                                                                         name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

где `selector` - это метод, который будет вызван при получении сообщения.

Обработать сообщение уже Вам нужно самостоятельно. В `userInfo` уведомления содержится множество полезной информации. Вот, например, как я их использую:

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    double duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        chatTable.contentInset = contentInsets;
        chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        UpdateFrameY(messageLayout, self.view.frame.size.height - (kbSize.height + messageLayout.frame.size.height));
        UpdateFrameWidth(messageView, messageView.frame.size.width - sendButton.frame.size.width - 8);
        [sendButton setAlpha:1.0];
    }];

    if ([self tableView:chatTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 0)
    [chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self tableView:chatTable numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    double duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        chatTable.contentInset = contentInsets;
        chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        UpdateFrameY(messageLayout, self.view.frame.size.height - messageLayout.frame.size.height);
        UpdateFrameWidth(messageView, messageView.frame.size.width + sendButton.frame.size.width + 8);
        [sendButton setAlpha:0.0];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Вот](http://snipplr.com/view/27423/) маленький сниппет для ObjC.

[Вот еще](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html), там внизу странички есть раздел notifications, можете посмотреть на какие еще события можно подписаться.

Comment: Спасибо, читаю.

Comment: Вопрос вдогонку: это расширение как заимплементить к существующему визуальному классу UISearchBar ?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то международные правила SO подразумевают более менее развернутый ответ на вопрос, а не просто вброс кода или ссылок.

Comment: @Nekto, если не ошибаюсь, то мы не SO. У меня не всегда есть время на развернутые ответы, а эти самые ответы нужны как можно быстрее, потому и скинул только ссылки, на мой взгляд их вполне достаточно чтобы решить проблему. А вообще и вопрос-то элементарный, гуглится за пять минут, если что.